# Integrating quick signup into an existing API that uses OAuth2 using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a web based API that I'm building that built in Spring Boot and uses OAuth2. The API is for a mobile application.

As part of the login for the mobile application, one of the options to login is using your Twitter/Facebook account.

My initial thoughts for this were to have the APP authenticate the user with Facebook/Twitter, and then pass the Token to the API. The API would then verify the token with Facebook/Twitter, collect the FB/Twitter Id and create a new account using that Id. The problem with this approach though is that I'm unsure how I go about also creating a Bearer token using the existing OAuth library, as during standard login (username/password) the OAuth library handles all of that.

The other option is to have the APP authenticate the user with Facebook/Twitter, then register the user as normal via the API using the users FB/Twitter Id as the username, but this 'feels' way less secure, but much easier to integrate.

At the minute the auth-tokens are stored by the OAuth library in a MySQL database table 'oauth_access_token'. I guess I could manually create the JWT and update this table myself.

I'm open to any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially an easier solution that the ones I initially raised in my question.

1) The mobile app authenticates the user with Facebook/Twitter and receives back a token.

2) The mobile app makes a request to my API [/users/quick-login] passing over the end users Facebook or Twitter Token.

3) The API uses the Facebook/Twitter token to get the user details from Facebook/Twitter. Once it has the user social media Id, we can search for the user in our database using that Id. If one doesn't exist, create the user using the information returned by Facebook/Twitter. For the users password we will encrypt the users Facebook/Twitter Id using a key that only the server knows. The password is then encrypted again before it's stored in the database as all of our passwords are. This ensures that the users password isn't just their Facebook/Twitter Id, as that would be too insecure.

4) Our API uses the email address as their username, and because we now know the users email address, and we know that the password is an encrypted version of the Facebook/Twitter Id, we can make a request to our own OAuth server [/oauth/token] passing across the the username/password, then we simply return that response to the mobile app.

To me this seems the most logical way to do it, especially since there's always a chance that the OAuth server may be operating on it's own hardware instance, and there 'could' be no directly access to it's classes from our API.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. The passwords are stored in the database using BCrypt which stores the password along with a salt. The only encryption I'll be using is to generate a password for the social media accounts. If a users twitter Id is 123456, I will create a password from that using an encryption key, then store the result in the database passing it through BCrypt first. Obviously if someone was to get hold of the project source code, they would be able to determine how we create the social passwords, but I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: An attacker will gain admin access to your server, that is how attacks work. Attackers are professionals, they go to work every day and work on attacking systems, it is a regular job. They are skilled, most likely substantially better skilled in security and cryptology than you and have excellent attack tools. Obviously you understand this to some extent or you would not bother with any cryptography on the server. If you have an encryption key stored in a file on the server it will be found and used. You will probably never know there was an attack.

Comment: Here s an interesting perspective: If you were going to hire a company to design this security would you hire a company with the level of security experience your company has?

Comment: Yes I agree. I've changed the way this working. When a new facebook/Twitter token is passed to the API, it finds the user in the database and randomly creates a new password and stores in in the DB(via BCrypt). Then we make a call to the standard OAuth/token endpoint passing over the newly created password.